# regasm and tlb (registering a .NET library for COM interop)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, com, regasm, typelib

I have .NET assembly with one public class and several private classes.

I am trying to register it for COM interop so that I can call it from VBA, using the following command:

`regasm /tlb foo.dll /codebase`

Subsequently, when I open up the `.tlb` file in Visual Studio's "object browser", I see that the library does not expose any types.

Any thoughts?

I realize that there isn't much specific information here, so if you let me know what would be diagnostically useful, I will try to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to mark my public type with `[ComVisible(true)]`.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to help:

1. I don't think that VS2008 object browser allows viewing of tlb files generated from .NET assemblies - I would recommend using [iTripoli's Type Library Viewer](http://www.itripoli.com/itlv.asp) to make sure that you are diagnosing the right problem;
2. Try using the `/verbose` option, to see what kind of problems `Regasm` has encountered.